# Odoo Server Error ubuntu

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

When try install any module get this error.

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 648, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 685, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 321, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 314, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 964, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 514, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 892, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 880, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 459, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 533, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 338, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 98, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 851, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/home/nolimit/git/odoo/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 917, in convert_xml_import
    doc = etree.parse(xmlfile)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3239, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:69955)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102257)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1789, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102516)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1684, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101442)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1134, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:97069)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757)
XMLSyntaxError: StartTag: invalid element name, line 8, column 4
```

Any solution how fix this problem?

Structure of module

Folder:  daily_transaction

**init**.py

```
daily_transaction
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
        'name': 'Daily Transaction Manager',
        'version': '1.0',
        'author': 'Lionel Messi',
        'complexity': 'normal',
        'description': 'New module',
        'category': '',
        'depends': [],
        'data': ['daily_transaction_view.xml'],
        'auto_install': False,
        'installable': True,
        'external_dependencies': {
            'python': [],
        },
    }
```

daily_transaction.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class daily_transaction(osv.osv):
    _name = "daily.transaction"
    _description = "Daily Transaction"

    _colums = {
        'subject': fields.char('Subject', size=128, required=True),
        'date': fields.date('Date', required=True),
        'note': fields.text('Notes'),
        'amount': fields.float('Amount', required=True),
        'type': fields.selection([
                  ('transport', 'Transport'),
                  ('household','Household'),
                  ('personal', 'Personal'),
                  ],'Type', required=True),                   
               }
```

daily_transaction_view.xml

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!--Daily Transaction List View-->          
        <record id="view_daily_transaction_tree" model="ir.ui.view"> 

        <!– here id is the external id for this tree view which must be unique and will be used for accessing this record -->           
        <field name="name">daily.transaction.tree</field> 

        <!– this will be our name of record in ir.ui.view -->           
        <field name="model">daily.transaction</field> 

        <!– this will map out tree view with our daily transaction model -->            
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <!-- this will be our title of list/tree view --> 
           <tree string="Daily Transaction"> <!-- these will automatically map table headers for our list view, so we’ll select out column names of our model here --> 
               <field name="name"/> 
               <field name="date"/> 
               <field name="type"/> 
               <field name="amount"/> 
           </tree> 
           </field>
        </record>           

         <!--Daily Transaction Form View--> 

         <record id="view_daily_transaction_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
         <field name="name">daily.transaction.form.view</field> 
         <field name="model">daily.transaction</field>
              <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
              <!-- this will be our title of list/tree view --> 
                  <form string="Daily Transaction" version="7.0"> 
                      <group> 
                          <field name="name"/> 
                          <field name="date"/> 
                          <field name="type"/>
                          <field name="amount"/>
                          <field name="note"/>
                      </group> 
                  </form> 
              </field> 
          </record>                       

        <record id="action_daily_transaction" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Daily Transaction</field> 
            <!– name of action --> 
            <field name="res_model">daily.transaction</field> 
            <!– this action will be mapped to model specified --> 
            <field name="view_type">form</field> 
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field> 
            <!-- these are type of view our module will show for our daily transaction mode --> 
            <field name="search_view_id" eval="False"/> 
            <!– here we specify id of our search view --> 
            <field name="context">{}</field> 
            <field name="help">Create new daily transaction.</field> 
            <!– help text for our model --> 
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

What is that? https://postimg.cc/image/csxssd7tx/

Module --> https://postimg.cc/image/gk1uyb0vn/

Comment: so is this odoo-8 or odoo-9?  can hardly be both. Also, what did you try to investigate? As your question is currently, it's not answerable. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include a lot more background, and an attempt on your own.

Comment: For example, the error already points you to a possible problem with a specific file. Did you have a look at that file? Did you read the error at all?

Comment: Not enough information

Comment: Provide the command or code or call you used to produce these error output. Please provide detailed informations about your plattform.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use odoo9, Im create simple module in eclipse, now in eclipse stay https://postimg.org/image/csxssd7tx/    daily transaction module  is example  how create frst module in odoo http://www.slideshare.net/TarunBehal1/odoo-open-erp-creating-a-module-37569034?next_slideshow=1

Comment: here is stuctue of module  https://postimg.org/image/gk1uyb0vn/

Comment: @user5109824 so remove the odoo-8 tag, your question mark question should be another question, don't post screenshots of program code but add the program code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forget to declare `name` field on your Class.

You can resolve it with following two option:

1. Add *name* field on your *class daily_transaction* OR
2. You may change field definition like

   ```
   'name': fields.char('Subject', size=128, required=True),
   ```

Afterwards, restart your reserver and upgrade module.

Comment: Here is full source code of this module, for begginer is great  https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=2349b98dd3d0e22d&id=2349B98DD3D0E22D%21186